# What is the C++ equivalent of the C# checked

Tags: c#, c++-cli, overflow

I'm looking to avoid an overflow in managed C++ (CLI). In C# there is an unchecked keyword, and in C++ overflows do not end up in exceptions.

For reference, unchecked is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Basically if you do:

```
unchecked
{
      int1 = 2147483647 + 10; //this overflows in CLI but is ok in C# and C++
}
```

In C# it will not overflow but convert to int by taking the least significant bits. This is appropriate when you compute hash codes for example.

Note: I realize there is no equivalent C++ keyword, but some bit shifting should do the trick;

Comment: `unchecked` is the default behavior (unless overriden by the compiler).

Comment: In managed C++ (CLI) you will get an overflow exception. I am editing the question.

Comment: You can always just use `#pragma unmanaged` to get the normal unchecked behavior in native C++.

Comment: @leppie - sounds like a good answer actually - you can move it from comments :)

Comment: @Mat - good point, I edited the question, thank you!

Comment: Your question is wrong, you certainly do not keep the most significant bits.  Doesn't really explain the downvotes, though.

Comment: Fixed - I meant LSB not MSB, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `#pragma unmanaged` around a method to get the normal unchecked behavior in native C++.

Answer (score 2):

Use an unsigned data type for bit operations and checksumming.  Wrap-around behavior of unsigned behavior is well-defined in C++.