# C++/CLI equivalent of C# checked keyword

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, overflow

Is there a way for managed code in C++/CLI to throw exceptions on arithmetic overflow? C# has the checked keyword and also global project flags to enable these, but I can find neither in C++/CLI...

My situation is that I am wrapping C++ libs in .NET. Sometimes the C++ native code overflows. I was/am considering moving some sensitive calculations to existing C++/CLI wrapper, but perhaps this is not possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the C++ equivalent of the C# checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500593/what-is-the-c-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-checked)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500593/what-is-the-c-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-checked

Comment: Huh! We posted that link almost at the EXACT same time :D

Comment: Right, so does this mean C++/CLI has checked arithmetic on always?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked duplicate make no sense, C++/CLI follows C++ conventions.  C++ has no built-in mechanism for detecting arithmetic overflow.

Using the *checked* and *unchecked* keywords was originally planned for future extensions of C++/CLI.  [Ecma-372](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm) is the current language standard and proposes this extension in appendix F.2.1.  This however never happened and is very unlikely to be ever implemented.

You'll thus have to implement overflow checking yourself.  You'll find some guidance in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c).

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by that linked question - seems quite misleading.